# Exception Handling in camel onWhen

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Camel in the integration Project to connect it to the Http Endpoint.
Now I am trying to implement a scenario such as when ever there is an exception while connecting to the HTTP endpoint , I should use the status code to decide whether to try re-delivery or else **continue**  the route.
Here is how am I trying to implement

```
  onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.DEBUG)
            .onWhen(new Predicate() {
                @Override
                public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {

                    HttpOperationFailedException e = exchange.getProperty(
                            Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT,
                            HttpOperationFailedException.class);

                    if (e.getStatusCode() == 400)
                        return true;
                    return false;
                }
            }).continued(true).maximumRedeliveries(2);
```

The problem is when ever the Predicate return false the route is stop. what I am trying to achieve is to continue the route.

Comment: Are you sure that in your if (e.getStatusCode() == 400) , the value 400 is not a String?

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti yes e.getStatusCode() returns a int.

Comment: How does the rest of your route look?

Comment: Do you have an `onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)` to handle other cases? This only checks for one specific case 400.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what I do: define 2 `onException()`, with opposite onWhen() condition, while one is true and another is false. When true, continue(true); when false, retry.

```java
onException(HttpFailedOperationException.class).onWhen(notFoundPredicate)
    .continue(true);

onException(HttpFailedOperationException.class).onWhen(otherSituationPredicate)
    .setMaximumRetry(3)
    ...
```

And you define 2 classes with same injection dependency, like `NotFoundJudgementBean`:

```java
public class NotFoundPredicate implements Predicate {
    @Inject
    NotFoundJudgementBean bean;

    @Override
    public boolean match(Exchange exchange) {
        return bean.judge(exchange);
    }
}
```

And in the other predicate, `return !bean.judge(exchange);`.